# SNS message body filtering s3 key ignore suffix

Tags: amazon-web-services, filter, amazon-sns

I have an s3 key that can either be `document/<date>/<uuid>-updated.json` or `document/<date>/<uuid>.json`. I am wanting to set up two separate subscriptions to two separate queues, with one queue only receiving the `updated.json` related events, and the other queue receiving the `<uuid>.json` events. What would that filter policy look like? I can't figure out how to get `anything-but` to work with a `suffix` on the filter policy for the message body.

What I have for the `-updated.json` subscription is:

```json
{
  "Records": {
    "s3": {
      "object": {
        "key": [
          {
            "prefix": "document"
          },
          {
            "suffix": "-updated.json"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I have for the `<uuid>.json` subscription is:

```json
{
  "Records": {
    "s3": {
      "object": {
        "key": [
          {
            "anything-but": [
              "updated.json"
            ]
          },
          {
            "prefix": "document"
          },
          {
            "suffix": ".json"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Whenever I publish a test message for each type of key that could be received, each one of the queues is still receiving both messages.

Comment: "each one of the queues is still receiving both messages"  Anything matching `-updated.json` also matches `.json`.  I don't think you can differentiate between those particular suffixes with SNS filters.  add something to the `<uuid>.json` like `-current.json` so that they both have an explicit, unique, suffix match.